how to add SSL to a port in ALMALINUX 8 using openlitespeed?
we have ALMALINUX 8.9:
[root@google]# more /etc/redhat-release
AlmaLinux release 8.9 (Midnight Oncilla)
[root@google]#

running with LiteSpeed 1.7.19
[root@google]# /usr/local/lsws/bin/lshttpd -v
LiteSpeed/1.7.19 Open (BUILD built: Tue Apr 16 15:14:26 UTC 2024)
        module versions:
        lsquic 3.3.2
        modgzip 1.1
        cache 1.66
        mod_security 1.4 (with libmodsecurity v3.0.12)
[root@google]#

and SSL run fine (https://web.com)
however when we open https://web.com:portX, this load our APP but the browsers launch a WARNING (web not SSL)
also when we ADD this lines into /usr/local/lsws/conf/httpd_config.conf the URL https://web.com:portX yes load SSL over https://web.com:portX, but we LOST our APP because now load default page https://web.com
listener ourAPP {
  map                     web.com web.com
  address                 *:portX
  secure                  1
  keyFile                  /etc/letsencrypt/live/web.com/privkey.pem
  certFile                 /etc/letsencrypt/live/web.com/fullchain.pem
}

how we can ADD support SSL over portX ?
